# API call throwing an error but not getting into onError() function

Tags: android, listener

The API call was throwing an error that I was trying to catch using onError(). For testing purpose I was trying to print a message in Log for onStarted(), onFinished and onError().
Message from onError() wasn't showing in Logcat but the message from onStarted() and onFinished() are being shown.

```
public void onAttach(android.app.Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
    TaskManager.registerListener(Bhr4Contracts.TASK_ROUTER, editWifiListener);

}

public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    TaskManager.unregisterListener(editWifiListener);

}

TaskStatusListener editWifiListener = new TaskStatusListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStarted(Bundle data) {
        Timber.tag("editListener").d("inside started");
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(Bundle data, Exception ex) {
        super.onError(data, ex);
        String message;
        if (ex instanceof NetworkingException) {
            message = ((NetworkingException) ex).getDetailedMessage();
            if (message.isEmpty()) {
                message = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
            }
        } else {
            message = ex.getMessage();
        }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
            Activity activity = getActivity();
            if (activity != null) {
                UIUtil.displayMessage(getActivity(), message, UIUtil.SNACKBAR_FLAG.IS_ERROR, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
            }
        }
        Timber.tag("editErrorListener").d("inside onError");
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinished(Bundle data) {
        Timber.tag("editListener").d("inside onFinished");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to show the error from API call using LocalBroadcastManager from the class, where API call was being made. I still couldn't figure out why **onError()** wasn't working but BroadcastReceiver worked as a workaround.